# How common are languages with different word orders in matrix and non-matrix clauses

Tags: linguistic-typology, word-order, relative-clauses

How common is it cross-linguistically for a language to have a different word order in various types of embedded clauses such as relative clauses?

[WALS](https://wals.info/feature) appears to collect information on word order in matrix clauses, but not specifically on various kinds of embedded clauses. Here are some examples of what I'm talking about from a fairly diverse group of languages.

---

The [Hixkaryana language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hixkaryana_language) apparently has OVSX word order in matrix clauses. An example of one is [in Laura Kalin's thesis](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/586960e5197aea52834230a2/t/5962cd259de4bb7b8d15d95c/1499647269809/Kalin-MA.pdf) on page 41, pdf page 49, example 58.

```
[bɨryekomo  komo  yonyetxkonɨ]               kamara [txetxa wawo] amnyehra
 child.COLL COLL  3s3o.eat-coll-distpst-cont jaguar  forest   in  long-ago
 The jaguar used to eat children in the forest long ago.
```

In nonmatrix clauses it is SOV. I don't know the order of the oblique in non-matrix clauses in Hixkaryana, but I *suspect* it is SXOV. I'm still combing through the thesis for relevant examples.

Also, some languages such as German have V2 word order in matrix clauses and SOV word order in embedded clauses. Although in other Germanic languages, the embedded clause word order is SVO.

[This article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.467.7114&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on Luganda mentions that in passing that several other Bantu languages besides Luganda invert the subject and verb and use a dedicated attributive verb form indicated with prefixing to form relative clauses.

> This is somewhat unusual – the more well-known
>   pattern in Bantu is for the relative marker either to be an ‘independent word’ preceding the subject, or a prefix on the verb with subject-verb inversion (Demuth and Harford 1999).

Comment: Can you define what is it a matrix clause? Not everyone is familiar with generativist terminology.

Comment: AFAIK, German and closely related languages are relatively unique in this regard, certainly within IE and also across language families.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer. Which "closely related" languages?

Comment: Was just hedging in case one of { Yiddish, Cimbrian, Bavarian, Luxembourgish... } etc have it too and even strictly require it.  (I know that not all require it, but I can't say that none do.)

Comment: "Matrix clause" just means "main clause".

Comment: The term 'matrix clause' is best reserved for those clauses within which a subordinate clause is embedded.

Comment: True. But that's the context they're asking about here.

Comment: I’m interested in the frequency of using different word orders in embedded clauses (or a subset of them, such as relative clauses) and non-embedded clauses.

Comment: For what it's worth, clitic order in subordinate clauses in Serbo-Croatian is also different from main clauses. In main clauses, clitics occupy the position right after the first phrase. In sub-clauses, clitics are initial. In Macedonian, verbs also tend to be initial in subclauses and post-initial in main clauses. This seems to at least be common in European languages.